# Use one-time-token field to determine if a message should be displayed

Tags: php, forms

I have a form, which has a "token" field that is unique for each page:

```
<form ...>
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="325324" />
</form>
```

This unique token gets stored in the database every time is generated.

When the form gets submitted, the controller that handles the processing will check the database to see if the submitted token field value exists in the database and do its stuff it it is.

After the stuff is done, the controller redirects to the same page, but adding a query argument to the url `?updated=1"`.

The page will display a message notifying the user who submitted the form, that his changes were updated, if that "updated" query argument exists.

So every thing is fine, except that if I refresh the page with the `?updated=1"` argument, I get to see the same message, which doesn't really reflect the reality, because the form is not submitted :)

I know this is not that important, because it's not a security issue, but still I'd want to get around it. I found a solution by creating another token, let's call it token2 that I pass to the URL when redirecting as query argument. Then, when the page checks for that `updated` argument, it will also check if token2 exists in the database. If it does, it will delete it, then display the message. So any further requests that have the same token2 argument in the URL will not trigger the message.

But I don't like the idea of storing two tokens in the database on each page. Can I somehow use the first token to detect if I should show the message or not?

Not sure if it matters, but these one-time-tokens expire after one hour, and all expired tokens get automatically deleted from the db twice a day.

Comment: Frankly I don't see any problem with this message displaying multiple times on a page refresh.  This indicates that the state of the page has not changed (in fact it hasn't).  Maybe you feel it would be confusing to your users..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding another field to this table (DB), named "submitted".

1.User gets to the form (token is generated)

2.Inserting `(token , submitted) values ('blabla' , '0')`

3.the user submit the form

4.the controller that handles the processing will check the database to see if the 
submitted token field value exists in the database and
    update the value of `submitted` to `1`.

5.the controller also reload the page with ?update=1 , then you'll have a condition:

```
if submitted == 1 : update submitted = 0
```

So , if the user now reload the page (notice that now submitted = 0) you'll show the form and not the message.

Comment: Interesting, but I can't really do that because I would have to modify the API that handles my database "transients" in a way that would affect other components using it.

Comment: Well , then you should try tandu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the DB for these tokens is fine, but I think you may be much better off using the session for this kind of data, especially because it's transient.  It could also simplify your code a bit.

As for your specific problem, people seem to forget that you can in fact execute code after you emit the view.  Your logic would be something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['updated']) {
   $view->addUpdatedMessage();
}
$_SESSION['updated'] = false;
```